# How to get previous index of only selected indexes

Tags: python

I am having trouble coming up with the logic to get the previous index based on my current index, where elements inbetween vary in numbers.

```
#list of students, created from dictionary so values are messy.
studentslist = ['name','bob','school','abc','extra element','remark','breakfast','name','mom','school','def','remark','Lunch','name','job','school','ghi','remark','Lunch']    

different_students=[]
selected_students=[]  

for i in studentslist:
    if 'remark' in i:
       #seperate each student by getting last index of each student e.g 3 students so, [5,11,17]
       different_students.append(studentslist.index[i])

      #getting index of students with lunch e.g [11,17]
       if 'Lunch' in studentlist:  
          selected_students.append(studentslist.index[i])  

#for loop to return values of selected students
for i in selected_students:
   for i in range(start,studentlist[i]):
      #need help getting start value
      #e.g range(0,5), range(5,11), and range(12,17) 
      #some students has additional elements so start cannot be hard coded with a fixed number.
      #expected output is to iterate and get all elements from specified #range, e.g range(0,5) to get first student name, school, ...etc
```

Comment: Can you add expected output? I didn't quite understand what is the end goal of the code.

Comment: Are you looking to split the studentslist into multiple lists and then only use a subset of those?

Comment: @Detective merry, the very first line of code, which is a comment, says that this data came from a dictionary. May we see that dictionary? Because I have a feeling that working with that dictionary will be much easier than turning the key-value pairs into a list, and then using indexes to pick and choose elements from that list.

Comment: I think you need to use dictionary. Look into python dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the if condition in the for loop for desired_ranges in mjake's answer was not really what I wanted, have made this so that if there is only element == 'Lunch' it will return (11,19) instead of (0,19)
changed students to stalls but the logic is there.

```
#create a list consisting of indexs of all different menu types
different_stall_no = [idx for idx,element in enumerate(list) if 'remark' in element]
different_stall_no1 = [x+1 for x in different_stall_no]
different_stall_no1.insert(0,0)

#print(different_stall_no1)

#retrieve selected stall's index number in list
selected_stall_no = [idx for idx,element in enumerate(list) if element == 'None']
#selected_stall_no.insert(0,0)
print(selected_stall_no)

desired_ranges = []

for idx, element in enumerate(different_stall_no1):
    for selectedstall in selected_stall_no
        if element == selectedstall:
            desired_ranges.append(different_stall_no1[idx-1])
            desired_ranges.append(selectedstall)

print(desired_ranges, 'this is desired range')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make extension use of enumerate, which generates the index and element as a pair for each iteration. I copied your code and found that selected_students only contains [12,18]. With that in mind, this solution should fit your needs.

```
studentslist = ['name','bob','school','abc','extra element','remark','breakfast','name','mom','school','def','remark','Lunch','name','job','school','ghi','remark','Lunch']    

different_students = [idx for idx,element in enumerate(studentslist) if element == 'remark']
selected_students = [idx for idx,element in enumerate(studentslist) if element == 'Lunch']

desired_ranges = []
for idx, element in enumerate(selected_students):
    if idx > 0:
        desired_ranges.append((selected_students[idx-1],element))
    else:        
        desired_ranges.append((0,element))

print(different_students)
print(selected_students)
print(desired_ranges)

>>>>[5, 11, 17]
>>>>[12, 18]
>>>>[(0, 12), (12, 18)]
```